# clearTimeout not working?

Tags: jquery

I'm currently working on my assignment.
Now i got an animation banner which cycles through different images.
Each functions linked to an image. Now everything is working fine. Just that when i try to clear the timer(stop cycling the images) when the element with id'contact' is mouseOver, i cant clear the timeout and it still keep looping. Please help.

```
var timer;

function cycle() {
    contact();
    timer = setTimeout("$('#contact').removeClass('hovered')", 2000);
    timer = setTimeout("photoGallery()", 2000);
    timer = setTimeout("$('#photoGallery').removeClass('hovered')", 4000);
    timer = setTimeout("programmes()", 4000);
    timer = setTimeout("$('#programmes').removeClass('hovered')", 6000);
    $("#contact").hover(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer)
    });
    timer = setTimeout("cycle()", 6000);
}
```

Comment: What is `contact();`, what is `photoGallery()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the `timer` every time

```
var timer;

function cycle() {

    contact();

    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $('#contact').removeClass('hovered');
        photoGallery();
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $('#photoGallery').removeClass('hovered')
            programmes();
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                $('#programmes').removeClass('hovered')
                programmes();
                cycle()
            }, 2000);
        }, 2000);
    }, 2000);


}

$("#contact").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer)
});
```